# Grep Syntax with Capitals

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to write a script with a file as an argument that greps the text file to find any word that starts with a capital and has 8 letters following it. I'm bad with syntax so I'll show you my code, I'm sure it's an easy fix.

```
grep -o '[A-Z][^ ]*' $1
```

I'm not sure how to specify that:

a) it starts with a capital letter, and

b)that it's a 9 letter word.

Cheers

EDIT:

As an edit I'd like to add my new code:

```
while read p
do
echo $p | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
done < $1
```

I still can't get it to work, any help on my new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'[A-Z][^ ]*'` will match one character between A and Z, followed by zero or more non-space characters.  So it would match any A-Z character on its own.

Use `\b` to indicate a word boundary, and a *quantifier* inside braces, for example:

```
grep '\b[A-Z][a-z]\{8\}\b'
```

If you just did `grep '[A-Z][a-z]\{8\}'` that would match (for example) "aaaaHellosailor".

I use `\{8\}`, the braces need to be escaped unless you use `grep -E`, also known as `egrep`, which uses Extended Regular Expressions.  Vanilla `grep`, that you are using, uses Basic Regular Expressions.  Also note that `\b` is not part of the standard, but commonly supported.

If you use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end then it will not find "Wiltshire" in "A Wiltshire pig makes great sausages", it will only find lines which *just* consist of a 9 character pronoun and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ echo "one-Abcdefgh.foo" | grep -o -E '[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
$ echo "one-Abcdefghi.foo" | grep -o -E '[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
Abcdefghi
$
```

Note that this doesn't handle extensions or prefixes.  If you want to FORCE the input to be a 9-letter capitalized word, we need to be more explicit:

```
$ echo "one-Abcdefghij.foo" | grep -o -E '\b[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}\b'
$ echo "Abcdefghij" | grep -o -E '\b[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}\b'
$ echo "Abcdefghi" | grep -o -E '\b[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}\b'
Abcdefghi
$
```

Comment: Why do you have the $ after {8}?

Comment: Also, right now I'm trying 


    grep -o -E '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}$' 

and I'm not getting anything, do I have to pipe into grep?

Comment: `^` and `$` are not the right anchors to use -- use `\<` and `\>` or  `\b` and `\b` to denote the boundaries of a word

Comment: @BernieMacinflor - you probably already figured out that I originally had an error in my answer, which is now corrected thanks to Glenn's suggestion.  As you know, grep's `-o` option tells it to print only the portion of the input that is described by the regex.  By putting word boundaries around the regex (`\b`), we ensure that we won't match strings like "ABcdefghijk" simply because the valid match ("Bcdefghij") is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a test file named 'testfile' with the following content:

```
Aabcdefgh
Babcdefgh
cabcdefgh
eabcd
```

Now you can use the following command to grep in this file:

```
grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}' testfile
```

The code above is equal to:

```
cat testfile | grep -Eo '^[A-Z][[:alpha:]]{8}'
```

This matches

```
Aabcdefgh
Babcdefgh
```

Comment: this refuses to work with my testfile Randomtext.txt.


It contains: The loud Brown Cow jumped over the White Moon. November October tesTer Abcdefgh Abcdefgha .


My code is the exact same as yours but with Randomtext.txt after it.

Comment: Can you edit you question with the test file so we can see where the line breaks are please?